# Difference between quit and exit in irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

Is there any difference between using quit or exit to quit irb?

E.g., are these functionally identical:

```
irb(main):001:0> quit
```

and

```
irb(main):001:0> exit
```

Comment: there's also `irb_exit`, if you needed another option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems so.

```
method(:quit).owner    #=> IRB::ExtendCommandBundle
method(:exit).owner    #=> IRB::ExtendCommandBundle
method(:exit).source_location
#=> ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/extend-command.rb", 28]
method(:quit).source_location
#=> ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/extend-command.rb", 28]
method(:exit) == method(:quit)    #=> true
```